# Manifest merger ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, android-manifest

I am facing build error after installing cordova-plugin-qrscanner
i have installed QR scanner using this command bellow

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-qrscanner
>
> npm install @ionic-native/qr-scanner

I have also import this to my app module
but after this when i am building apk, getting err

> F:\Project 2\EzeeAccess\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:44:5-90 Error:
>           Element uses-permission#android.permission.CAMERA at AndroidManifest.xml:44:5-90 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:41:5-65
>   :app:processDebugManifest

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

> :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
>   28 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 26 up-to-date
>   F:\Project 2\EzeeAccess\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:45:5-85 Error:
>           Element uses-feature#android.hardware.camera at AndroidManifest.xml:45:5-85 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:43:5-84
>   F:\Project 2\EzeeAccess\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
>           Validation failed, exiting

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I have also installed cordova Camera plugin

Probably these lines causing the problem in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

and this is my android.json

```
{
    "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.CAMERA\" android:required=\"false\" />",
    "count": 1
},
{
    "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.CAMERA\" />",
    "count": 1
 },
{
   "xml": "<uses-feature android:name=\"android.hardware.camera\" android:required=\"true\" />",
   "count": 1
},
{
  "xml": "<uses-feature android:name=\"android.hardware.camera\" android:required=\"false\" />",
  "count": 1
},
{
  "xml": "<uses-feature android:name=\"android.hardware.camera.front\" android:required=\"false\" />",
  "count": 1
}
```

please help

Comment: Hey, how did you resolve this?